# Urls in CanonicalUrl Rendering Showing Http Instead of Https

Tags: sxa, links, seo

I'm hoping this is an easy one. The `CanonicalUrl` rendering in the `Metadata Partial design` isn't honoring our `https` settings for the website.

Instead, it always shows `http` in the `canonical link` for every page on the site.

Am I missing a setting somewhere? All sites are set to use the https protocol. Before I start investigating the dll I figured I would ask! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Canonical URL is a part of `Metadata Snippet Layout.cshtml`

The metadata partial design is different from the regular partial design because it uses a metadata layout `(Layouts/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Presentation/Metadata Layout)`. This layout is bound to `/Views/SXA/Metadata Snippet Layout.cshtml` and contains the following placeholders:

- head
- body-top
- body-bottom

CanonicalURL is a part of the head placeholder and Renders the canonical URL of the page. It's been part of `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.dll`

There is a `CanonicalUrlRepository` and it has a method called `GetModel`. Here, you can find how it prepares URL and uses `url.Scheme` from the current request URL `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`.

```
public CanonicalUrlModel GetModel(Item item)
    {
        ItemUrlBuilderOptions urlOptions = UrlOptionsProvider.GetUrlOptions();
        string text = Context.Site.SiteInfo.ResolveTargetHostName();
        Uri url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        string itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
        return new CanonicalUrlModel
        {
            Url = url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + text + itemUrl
        };
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it’s by design. Nginx ingress handles TLS termination, so the pods listen on port 80 (http). Will add my own module. Thanks for the response! Helped to see the schema coming in.